# go generate command on faucet.html not working

Tags: go-ethereum

I forked go-ethereum, i made some modification to the faucet.html, and used 'go generate' command to persist the changes to Geth, but when i use Puppeth to generate my faucet, the changes i made on the faucet.html does not reflect.

I have tried to make the modification severally on faucet.html, persisting my modification using 'go generate' command and generating my faucet, yet my changes does not reflect.

please i need urgent help on how to make changes to faucet.html, persist the changes and to see the changes reflect on my generated faucet. Thank you.